# Excel - Data Validation Drop Down List - Can you make it have more than 8 lines?

Tags: excel, validation

I have a longer set of data for a drop down list (25 options) but excel only displays 8 at a time. See example photo. Is there a way to set it to display more? Would love it to display 12 or more.

[image]

Comment: I don't think is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with a list box, but a combo-box might be an appropriate alternative. They're not exactly the same, but it does give you a drop down for which you can say how many items to show in the list.

Here's the Office support on how to [add a list box or combo box to a worksheet in excel](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-in-excel-579e1958-f7f6-41ae-ba0c-c83cc6e40878).